# running tostring in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tostring

I did read other questions and I see that

```
class T:
  def ___str___(self):
     return 'boo'



r=T()
print(r) # should print boo
```

But, I am missing something here
I am getting the Object address in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra underscore in the name, use

```
__str__
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `__str__`, not `___str___`.

```
>>> class T:
...   def __str__(self):
...      return 'boo'
...
>>> r=T()
>>> print(r)
boo
```

Comment: Double underscores... The bane of Python programmers everywhere.